# Cabin subfloor after roof

Tags: framing

I am building a cabin in the woods (pier and beam foundation) and I want to insulate the floor. I will not be able to go under the cabin once everything is done because it won’t sit high enough. I could block the underneath of the joist, fill with foam board, add vapor barrier then subfloor but it will get rained on for an extended time before I will have a roof on (3-6 months).

Alternatively, I was thinking of framing my external walls directly on the beam, putting up my roof then doing the insulation and the subfloor. It is apparently how they do it in Northern Europe, but I have never seen that done in the US. Any recommendations?

Comment: Letting it get rained on for 3-6 months sounds like a bad plan, especially if there's a chance that "6 months" could push into winter and become "next year".  Also make sure to flame-test any foam materials you think about using - their supposed fire resistance is grossly exaggerated - ask the Grenfell Towers, Browns Ferry nuclear plant, or Sunshine Mine (how on earth can you even *have* a fire in a hard-rock mine let alone asphyxiate 100 people?)   See a live-fire test here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdItsso3ur0

Comment: Are you a one-man band with primitive tools, or what? You shouldn't have _any_ of your lumber exposed to the weather that long. Don't build the floor until you can build the roof. It's just a bad plan. Maybe if you revise to tell us more we can offer better suggestions.

Comment: Thanks! Yes that’s exactly that. One man, learning, primitive battery powered hand tools and week end only… realistically, if once I have the floor up it will take 2 to 4 week-ends to frame the walls then probably another 3 to 4 for the rafters and probably a couple more for the roof sheating. That is if I can go every week ends with no break due to weather or familly need. 
I think I’ll forget the insulation under the cabin and raise the door to insulate from the inside when all is done.

Answer (score 0):

I would lay the sub floor sheets down but not nail/screw them down.

Can pull them up easy to do work under the floor.

This is to give you a safe work platform for doing the walls/roof without worrying about where to step.

I am assuming this cabin is not that large and only a few sheets of 4x8 is used.

Comment: Hello, thanks! That’s a good idea but how about under the walls? I won’t be able to lift if I have my walls nailed down, especially in the corner. Would you nailed the walls straight to the rim and butt the subfloor onto it? The cabin is going to be 16’x24’.

Comment: Do you think you work on the insulation from just the centre of the floor open?  It will be nice to have the walls on the sub floor, since measurements/lack of cutting might be easier.  One sheet could be cut in half for the centre section.